# Rollback in lucene

Tags: c#, lucene

Is there a rollback in lucene?

I'm saving & updating database repository & lucene repository simultaneously so that the lucene index & database are in sync..

ex.

```
CustomerRepository.add(customer);
SupplierRepository.add(supplier);

CustomerLuceneRepository.add(customer); 
SupplierLuceneRepository.add(supplier); // If this here fails i cannot rollback the customer above

DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not completely sure on how you are using Lucene or how the C# version differs from the Java version, but at least `IndexWriter` in Java contains methods for `commit` and `rollback`. If you could post some implementation code that would probably help.

Comment: unfortunately, i'm using lucene.net in C# and there's no commit & rollback method as i'd double checked. I don't know why they didn't include it..

Comment: Have you seen this blog post http://www.lybecker.com/blog/2009/12/03/lucene-net-and-transactions/? I checked the API documentation for Lucene.net 2.4.0 at http://lucene.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.4.0/ and IndexWriter seems to contain methods for commit and rollback.

Comment: Hi Ponzao, you are right. Those methods exist in 2.4 version. Currently, im using 2.3. Need to get latest =).. thank you very much for pointing that out. Appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. Good thing it was just a version problem.